# jquery tools validation re-bind after loading different content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bind

I'm using the jquery tools validation plugin for client side form validation.
i have one javascript file which loads the function below on ready.

What i'm doing is, i load a form, when this is being validated successfully and submitted,
i load another form, and would like the function below to handle any form thats being loaded
within the if (json.success && json.next) statement block.

For some reason, when the second form is loaded, the validator is not being re-bound to the
class (.signup_form) of the new form, and the validation does not occur.

any idea how i could attach a $.live or anything to this, so it'll automatically rebind itself to whatever form gets loaded with the .signup_form class after success?

```
/* For clarification: json.next is the url of the next form to load */

$(".signup_form").validator({
position: 'top left', 
offset: [-12, 0],
message: '<div><em/></div>' // em element is the arrow
}).submit(function(e) {

  var form = $(this);

  // client-side validation OK.
  if(!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {

    // submit with AJAX
    $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(json) {

      // everything is ok. (server returned true)
      if (json.success && json.next)  {
        form.parent().parent().load(json.next); // Slide here
        form.reset();

      // server-side validation failed. use invalidate() to show errors
      } else {
        form.data("validator").invalidate(json);
      }
    }, "json");

    // prevent default form submission logic
    e.preventDefault();

  }
});
```

any help is greatly appreciated.
T

**Okay, i figured it out... geez its so obvious.**

so all of the code above i have within a

```
form_listener = function() {}
```

block.

now all i need do do is to call the form listener after i load the new form:

```
.
.
      // everything is ok. (server returned true)
      if (json.success && json.next)  {
        form.parent().parent().load(json.next, function(){
        form_listener();
      });

.
.
```

sweet.

Comment: have you tried with the "live" function

Comment: well there is nothing i can bind the 'live' to. since there's no click or anything.. anyways, i _just_ now figured it out.. of course. i try to find a solution all day, and 4 minutes after i post here i figure it out :)

Comment: that is good, so answer your qustion.

Comment: I suggest you add the code in your form_listener function which actually does the rebind as currently its confusing.